# TFS update a project

Tags: c#, version-control, tfs, nopcommerce

I am a software developer working on a webshop. We are using nopCommerce 3.30 with custom plugins. The whole project is checked in on a TFS server. (Visual studio 2013, Team Foundation server 2012)

The problem is the following:
nopCommerce 3.40 was released, we downloaded the ZIP with the source code, but i am not sure how do i compare the diferences and check-in the new version. I can't just replace all files because i need to compare the folder structure / delete the files and folders that are not in 3.40 version.

Is there any compare function between 2 projects on either the client or server side ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using local workspaces, you can just delete all the code in your workspace, then copy the new code into the same workspace folder.  Then examine the pending changes window.  TFS will automatically detect all add/deletes/edits (you may have to promote some of the changes from the Excluded Changes section of the Pending Changes window).

Answer (score 1):

extract the files to a local folder, you can then use the compare tool.

Map one side to the source location of the original package, map the other side to your local directory. this will show you differences in the folder structure, file names etc. you can repeat / drill down to do the same at the file level

Comment: But there are some files that does not need to be published to TFS, such as .suo files etc. Also how to ensure to remove files that are not needed anymore (when using newer version). Will try and play with compare tool for sure. Thank you